# How to Toggle UIWebView Text when scalespagetofit = NO?

Tags: ios4, uiwebview, iphone-sdk-3.0

When I set the scalesPageToFit = YES in (checked in IB) I can pinch to zoom the webview but the initial load of the text is too small for the webView.

[image]
If I set scalesPageToFit = NO in (unchecked in IB) then the Text feed scales properly upon loading, but now the user can not pinch to zoom the Text

[image]

Anyone know of a way to do this? Pls help me?

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep scalesPageToFit = YES but also set the viewport so that it starts with the standard iPhone width. To set to the width of the device, add this to your HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width">       
</head>
...
```